# Change autofilled package name in Eclipse's New Class dialog

Tags: java, eclipse

I teach very early coders using Eclipse, so it's imperative that I minimize distractions for them.  I have all my preferences correct in Eclipse except for one: when I select "New Class", the name of the current Java Project autofills into the package field.  See the image below.  This is a problem because if they don't delete that content (every time!) it automatically creates a line

`package my_package_name;`

at the beginning of their new classes.  While I know this isn't a huge deal, I worry that it's just one more thing for them to worry about ("Is that why my code is wrong?").  Is there any way to change the default content of the "Package" field in the New Class window to be blank (so it wouldn't create the package line in their source code files)?

[image: image of autofilled package field in new class window]

Comment: I would try not to use the default package at all costs. Using this will definitely yield problems in the future. Therefore I would just teach them correctly what a package is.

Comment: Its highly recommended that we put every class in some package. so you should explain use of package rather then removing it